# Finding a repeating pattern in a given string

Tags: c#, vb.net, split

I have a networkstream (using C#/VB.NET). while on reading values coming like this:

```
&%       68 kg      K    A&%       23 kg      K    A&%      174 kg      K    A &%       68 kg     
&%       34 kg      K    A&%     2334 kg      K    A&%       68 kg      K    A &%       68 kg      K    A
&%     2348 kg      K    A&%       78 kg      K    A&%       28 kg      K    A&%       68 kg
```

The numerical(weight) value will be continuously varying.

Every time i am reading the starting of the stream differs. But the pattern remains the same. 
How to split that into '&%       78 kg      K    A' which represents one set.

How to extract the weight value from this stream using Regex or any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try.

```
 string str="&%       68 kg      K    A&%       23 kg      K    A&%      174 kg";
 string []ar=Regex.Split(str,@"[^0-9]").Where(p=> p!=string.Empty).ToArray();
```